# How do I toggle the readonly attribute of all child element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## Description

So I have a form that has a button that when clicked I would like to toggle the readonly attribute of all child elements of a fieldset.

## The HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset id="F1">
        <textarea id="T1" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea><br>
        <textarea id="T2" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea><br>
        <textarea id="T3" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea><br>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="button" id="button" onclick="togglerequire('#F1')">
        Click Me
        </button>
</form>
```

## The jquery:

```
function togglerequire(id){
    $(id).children().each(function(){
        var re = $(this).prop('required');
        $(this).prop('required', !re);
    });
}
```

## Back to the Question:

I can get this to work for individual elements by id but as soon as I attempt to perform the toggle on child elements defined by the parent id, it stops working and I can't figure out why.

Comment: You want to toggle the readonly property as well as the required property, or instead of?

Comment: as well as but if I can figure out how to do one I assumed I would be able to do it for both.

Comment: You can, but there's absolutely no need when there's a far simpler alternative; my answer, below, might be easier to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the function to following

```
function togglerequire(id){
    $(id).children("textarea").each(function(){
        var re = $(this).prop('readonly'); 
        $(this).prop('readonly', !re);
    });
}
```

Please note you were toggling the wrong property. Additionally, it is better we can provide the specific selector like textarea or class etc.

Comment: Actually, the idea was to set both properties but I do appear to have mentioned the wrong one. How would it work if there were different child elements?

Comment: Then you case try following **children("textarea, input")**

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `jquery` so you can find an element and get all its children having `readonly` and then call `.toggle` like the following snippet:-

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
   $('#F1').children('[readonly]').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="F1">
    <textarea id="T1" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea><br>
    <textarea id="T2" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea><br>
    <textarea id="T3" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea><br>
</fieldset>
<button type="button" id="button">Click Me</button>
```

And same is the case for required or both readonly and required like:

```
$('#F1').children('[required]').toggle();// Correct
$('#F1').children('[readonly]').toggle();// Correct
$('#F1').children('[readonly][required]').toggle();// Correct

$('#F1').children('readonly').toggle();// incorrect
```

**Note**: If you will try to get Childerns without `[]` for `readonly` like `$('#F1').children('readonly').toggle();` this will not toggle. You need to put `[]` around `readonly` or `required` or both.

**Update 1**

As you wanted to make them `readonly`. Here is the snippet which will make all child elements having `required` attribute, `readonly` at `click` `event`.

```js
$('#button').click(function(){
   $('#F1').children('[required]').prop('readonly', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="F1">
    <textarea id="T1" rows="5" cols="50"  required></textarea><br>
    <textarea id="T2" rows="5" cols="50"  required></textarea><br>
    <textarea id="T3" rows="5" cols="50"  required></textarea><br>
</fieldset>
<button type="button" id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work, it appears to hide the text areas and not define them as readonly

Comment: @Petay87 its toggling text areas. You can try both required and readonly

Comment: I don't want it to toggle the textarea being visible the question was how do I set them as readonly

Comment: Pardon but your question title was How do i toggle you did not mention that you want to make them read only. As you have already mentioned that those are readonly.

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer, I'd suggest that if the intent is to prevent user-interaction with the `<textarea>` elements in the `:disabled`/`readonly` state, then it's easier to avoid iterating over those children, and instead assign the `disabled` property to the parent `<fieldset>`:

```
// named function to call:
function toggleActiveStatus() {

  // I'm using native DOM approaches here simply because
  // they're 'cheaper' (premature optimisation, however)
  // than invoking jQuery unnecessarily.

  // here we use let statement to assign the element found
  // by 'document.querySelector()' (which returns the first
  // element matching the supplied CSS selector, or null if
  // there is no matching element) to the 'parent' variable:
  let parent = document.querySelector(

    // here we retrieve the CSS selector held in the
    // <button> element's 'data-affects' custom
    // (and valid) data-* attribute:
    this.dataset.affects
  ),

    // here we find the current state of the
    // element, returned as a Boolean true
    // if the <fieldset> is disabled or
    // false if the <fieldset> is not
    // disabled:
    currentState = parent.disabled;

  // here we simply set the disabled property
  // of the <fieldset> to the inverse of its
  // current state:
  parent.disabled = !currentState;

}

// binding the named function (note the deliberate
// lack of parentheses) using jQuery, rather than
// in-line event-handlers, to avoid the use of
// difficult-to-maintain JavaScript, and switching
// to the 'unobtrusive' JavaScript approach:
$('#button').on('click', toggleActiveStatus);
```

```js
function toggleActiveStatus() {
  let parent = document.querySelector(this.dataset.affects),
    currentState = parent.disabled;

  parent.disabled = !currentState;

}

$('#button').on('click', toggleActiveStatus);
```

```css
body {
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
}

button {
  text-transform: sentence;
}

#F1:disabled+button::before {
  content: "enable";
}

#F1:not(:disabled)+button::before {
  content: "disable";
}

#F1+button::after {
  content: ' textarea elements';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset id="F1">
    <textarea id="T1" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea>
    <textarea id="T2" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea>
    <textarea id="T3" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="button" id="button" data-affects="#F1"></button>
</form>
```

Also, as jQuery is in no way necessary for this approach, the following shows a pure JavaScript approach, using the native DOM API:

```
function toggleActiveStatus() {
  let parent = document.querySelector(this.dataset.affects),
    currentState = parent.disabled;

  parent.disabled = !currentState;

}

// here we use document.querySelector(), as above, to find
// the first element matching the supplied CSS selector:
document.querySelector('#button')

  // and then use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind
  // the named function (again: note the deliberate lack
  // of parentheses) as the event-handler for the 'click'
  // event:
  .addEventListener('click', toggleActiveStatus);
```

```js
function toggleActiveStatus() {
  let parent = document.querySelector(this.dataset.affects),
    currentState = parent.disabled;

  parent.disabled = !currentState;

}

document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', toggleActiveStatus);
```

```css
body {
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
}

button {
  text-transform: sentence;
}

#F1:disabled+button::before {
  content: "enable";
}

#F1:not(:disabled)+button::before {
  content: "disable";
}

#F1+button::after {
  content: ' textarea elements';
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset id="F1">
    <textarea id="T1" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea>
    <textarea id="T2" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea>
    <textarea id="T3" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="button" id="button" data-affects="#F1"></button>
</form>
```

References:

- HTML:

  - [Custom `data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*).
- JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`HTMLFieldsetElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFieldSetElement).
  - [`let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).
  - [Logical NOT (`!`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)).
- jQuery:

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function toggleAttributesOn(selector, elementSelector, attribute) {
   var container = document.querySelector(selector);
   if(!!container && !!attribute) {
     var elements = [].slice.call(container.querySelectorAll(elementSelector));
     elements.forEach(function(element) {
       if(['readonly', 'required'].indexOf(attribute) > -1) {
         element.getAttribute(attribute) !== null? element.removeAttribute(attribute): element.setAttribute(attribute, true); 
       }
       else {
         element.setAttribute(attribute, !element.getAttribute(attribute));
       }
     });
   }
}



// demo code
function togglerequire(selector) {
   toggleAttributesOn(selector, 'textarea', 'readonly');
}
```

```html
<form>
    <fieldset id="F1">
        <textarea id="T1" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea><br>
        <textarea id="T2" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea><br>
        <textarea id="T3" rows="5" cols="50" readonly required></textarea><br>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="button" id="button" onclick="togglerequire('#F1')">
        Click Me
        </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.
Grabs all inputs within this div and marks them as disabled.

$("#divID:input").attr("disabled", true);